# dotfile management for different machines with git branches reasonable?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, remote-branch, dotfiles

I set myself up a dotfiles repo, hosted on a remote server and used on different machines. For some things I'd like to have individual configurations, e.g. the environment variables differ between machines.

I thought, it would be nice to have an extra branch for the machine-dependent changes, so for example I have the branches `server`, `notebook`, `desktop`, all based on `master` with little individual changes (1 to a few commits).
Now the problem is, I want to have those individual changes applied on top, obviously. So I'd alter `master` for common changes and `rebase` the local `desktop` branch upon that. But using `rebase`, I can't `push` to the remote repo anymore. And I want that, as backup and for syncing, obviously, and it also might happen that I want to alter the branch of machine A while actually working on machine B.

Is it at all reasonable to maintain a single branch for every machine or is there a better solution?
How would I be able to apply the local changes on top, as with rebase, but not losing the ability to `push`?
Thanks very much

Comment: Would it be an option to store all machine-dependent variable in a single file, and have a git hook propagate the values when necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Your multiple branches approach sounds reasonable, and is the solution of some issues I was having with machine specific scripts (work/personal).

The problem you're describing is that you cannot push changes after doing a `git rebase`.

The reason you can't push is because `git rebase` rewrites history. It removes your branch specific commits, syncs with master and reapplies the commits on top:

[image]

## Why not merge instead of rebase?

By merging (`git merge master`) you won't rewrite history and you won't have problems pushing to your remote.

I recommend you read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/the-golden-rule-of-rebasing/) article, it explains the difference between merge and rebasse.

If you really need/want to rebase, you'll have to force push your changes to your remote by running `git push --force <remote_name> <branch_name>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also include files in your gitconfig

```
[include]
   path = ~/my_std_git_config
```

So you could have one common file with standard stuff. And several gitconfig files for your different hosts.

Then link only one of the host specific gitconfigs to ~/.gitconfig . 
Keep all files together in one branch.

i.E. in your repository:

```
common_gitconfig
laptop_gitconfig
server_gitconfig
```

Include common_gitconfig into laptop_* and server_* .
Link your laptop_gitconfig to ~/.gitconfig on your laptop. On your server link server_gitconfig.